# IonIcons remove spacing

Tags: css, ionicons

How to remove spacing from top and bottom on Ion Icons?

I use it in my html like :

`<div><i className="close ion-ios-close-empty" /></div>`

and this is default style for all ionicons:

```
display:inline-block;
font-family:"Ionicons";
speak:none;
font-style:normal;
font-weight:normal;
font-variant:normal;
text-transform:none;
text-rendering:auto;
line-height:1;
font-size: inherit;
-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale
```

And close class is as follows :

```
.close{
   color: #ffffff;
   font-size: 50px;
}
```

[image]

I didn't add any style to it, I only increased font-size, but the icon is shown like on the photo.

Is there any way to remove the spacing on top and bottom?

Comment: Can you provide minimal code, please!

Comment: @Aroniaina That is default code. Just like by font awesome. I added it.

Comment: Please check this: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit later, but my solution is to set the line-height to 0.6 em:

```
.close{
   color: #ffffff;
   font-size: 50px;
   line-height: 0.6em;
}
```

It's more like a work around, but if you play a liite bit with the line-height property, you can get good results.

Hint: If you want to choose shadow, use text-shadow and not box-shadow.

Answer (score -1):

Use line height property if you want 20px height.
Example:

```css
[selector] {
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: then set height how much you want and adjust by negative margin